# What does 'Left to walk the last yards into Austria' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> **Left to walk the last yards into Austria**, rain-soaked migrants, many of them refugees from Syria's civil war, were whisked by train and shuttle bus to Vienna, where many said they were resolved to continue on to Germany.

<sup>Source: [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/09/05/us-europe-migrants-hungary-idUSKCN0R40FO20150905), [Newsweek](http://www.newsweek.com/austria-germany-accept-migrants-hungary-369125) et al.</sup>

Comment: The sentence doesn't *mean* anything because it is incorrect. There is no subject in the sentence.

Comment: I found (and corrected) the article, still you should state *what you think it means*.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary for various meanings of "left"? Or "yard"? What meaning do you guess, and why do you think that is not the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the sentence can be broken into multiple parts.

The subject is the "rain-soaked migrants." They are left alone to walk the remaining distance into the country of Austria.

The next part of the sentence describes the refugees' past. It is followed and finished by describing what is happening to them, where they are going.

Comment: Also to clarify, "yard" in this context is a unit of distance slightly less than one meter, currently used primarily in the USA. So "the last yards" would be a very short distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yard

Answer (score 0):

It means leaving the rest of the rain-soaked migrants to walk the final distance into Austria.